# Why date and time become NA after using `xts`

Tags: r, xts

My original data looks like this:

```
                    V1     V2     V3
 1 01/01/04 07:43:00 1.2587 1.2597
 2 01/01/04 07:47:52 1.2585 1.2595
 3 01/01/04 17:46:14 1.2586 1.2596
 4 01/01/04 17:56:08 1.2585 1.2595
 5 01/01/04 17:56:15 1.2585 1.2595
 6 01/01/04 17:56:28 1.2585 1.2595

......


                       V1     V2     V3
2105023 31/03/04 23:59:46 1.2302 1.2304
2105024 31/03/04 23:59:50 1.2303 1.2305
2105025 31/03/04 23:59:50 1.2301 1.2303
2105026 31/03/04 23:59:51 1.2302 1.2304
2105027 31/03/04 23:59:55 1.2301 1.2303
2105028 01/04/04 00:00:00 1.2302 1.2304
```

I would like to convert it to data that I can use for `xts` and following is my code:

```
V.xts <- xts(V[, 2:3], order.by=as.POSIXct(V[, 1], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'))
```

And the following is what I got:

```
                            V2     V3
    2004-01-01 07:43:00 1.2587 1.2597
    2004-01-01 07:47:52 1.2585 1.2595
    2004-01-01 17:46:14 1.2586 1.2596
    2004-01-01 17:56:08 1.2585 1.2595
    2004-01-01 17:56:15 1.2585 1.2595
    2004-01-01 17:56:28 1.2585 1.2595
```

However, the end part of my data does not have Date and time, it looks like this:

```
         V2     V3
<NA> 1.2303 1.2305
<NA> 1.2302 1.2304
<NA> 1.2303 1.2305
<NA> 1.2301 1.2303
<NA> 1.2302 1.2304
<NA> 1.2301 1.2303
```

I am learning how to use package `xts` to analyse my high frequency data and I dont know if I got it wrong when I try to create data object using `xts`. I will appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Check the month/day order perhaps. `01/01` is valid as day/month or month/day, but `31/03` is only valid as day/month.

Comment: thanks @CraigMcQueen, silly me because I thought `order.by=as.POSIXct(V[, 1], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'` will also change the order of the date and time in my original data as `mm/dd/yyy` and then convert to `xts` data object with same order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the month/day order. `01/01` is valid as day/month or month/day, but `31/03` is only valid as day/month.